# How to trigger click on <select> on click of button

Tags: android, jquery, html, mobile

We have a select box and a button like shown below. Need to fake a click on the select when the user actually clicks on the "menu-item" label. When clicked on the "menu-item" label the select should open.

```
 <label class="menu-item" for="xyz">Sort by</label>
 <select name="" id="xyz" class="xyz-select">
   <option value="">hey</option>
   <option value="">hi</option>
   <option value="">yo</option>
 </select>
```

Expected results : the select box should open up on click of the label
Current Behavior : the select box opens on iphone but fails to show on android

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to say you can't. iOS devices such as iPhones and iPads will trigger the dropdown as they hook into a system UI control, unlike desktop and android browsers which generally use the built-in operating system control, which forbids access via the focus event - which is the current behavior of your code. 
Briefly speaking, the `<label for=''>` tag can only focus on your `<select>` element, not open it. This is false for iOS devices, but true for basically everything else.